# Where did I go wrong in solving this differential equation by substitution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+3y}{x-y}$ and am trying to solve by substituting $y=xv(x)$.  This results in $xv'+v=\frac{1+3v}{1-v}$.  By seperating the variables and integrating I get $\frac{v-1}{v+1}-\ln\left|{v+1}\right|=\ln\left|{x}\right|+C$.  Finally, substituting $v=\frac yx$ back in and rearranging yields $\frac{y-x}{y+x}-\ln\left|y+x\right|=C$.

However, the answer key shows $\frac{2x}{x+y}+\ln\left|x+y\right|=C$ and I am having trouble seeing where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not go wrong: your answer and the given answer are equivalent.

Note that $\frac{y-x}{y+x}=1-\frac{2x}{y+x}$.  So your answer can be rewritten as
$$1-\frac{2x}{y+x}-\ln(y+x)=C.$$
Multiply through by $-1$, and rearrange.  We get
$$\frac{2x}{y+x}+\ln(y+x)=1-C.$$
Since the constant of integration is arbitrary, that is the same answer as the given one.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't see that equivalence at all.

Comment: You are welcome. Similar issues come up in calculating indefinite integrals.